# FEAL-4 Вопрос по Fk-функции

Tags: криптография, шифрование

Здравствуйте!

Появился вопрос о Fk-функции в FEAL-4. Т.к. нам требуется 4 пары раундовых ключей - (k0,k1) (k2,k3) (k4,k5) (k6,k7) - нужно 4 раза запустить Fk-функцию. Но на 1 раунде, когда будет подаваться оригинальный 64-битный ключ, на выходе мы получим 32-битный ключ. То есть на 2 раунде в Fk-функцию опять нужно подавать 64-битный ключ, но ведь в 1 раунде получился ключ размером 32 бита. Для 2 раунда остальные значения будут нулями? 1 часть (32 бита) - это наш ключ из 1 раунда, а 2 32 битная часть будет нулями? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Для генерации 2-го этапа, грубо говоря, 32-битовый результат 1-го раунда используется совместно с половинкой оригинального 64-битового ключа. Это очень грубо, в реальности все немного сложнее. Посмотрите [на эту статью](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/spring2013/482/team/g1/report.pdf) - 4-я страница дает понятие, как работает Key Schedule с функцией Fk.